# Matrix resizing function in GNU Octave

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave

There is a function called as `resizem` in MATLAB which resize the input matrix to the specified size using some interpolation method.

Anybody knows any function in OCTAVE which do the same matrix resizing? There is a function `resize` in OCTAVE but its doing some thing else.

Answer (score 1):

The function `resizem` belongs to the Matlab mapping toolbox. It is not part of the core Matlab so you will not find it in Octave either.  You would find it the Octave mapping package (if it was implemented there which is not yet).

However, at first glance it seems to be simple to replace it with handling [`interp2`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/interp2.html) yourself, or use the image package [`imresize`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/image/function/imresize.html) as a drop-in replacement. That's all dependent on how you are using `resizem`.